# quartz job data-store persistence issue

Tags: java, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I have the following question.

- I have quartz scheduler 2.2.1
- I have jdbc datastore
- I have marked the job as Persistent
- I can see the trigger and the job info saved into the db.

Yet, it seems my job datamap information does not survive an application restart.

When I restart the application the data I saved into the datamap seem to disappear and the datamap is empty when the application is restarted.

```
context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().putAsString(LAST_EXEC, curTimeMilliSecs);
```

I have the following in the jobs.xml

```
    <job>
        <name>check-new-events-job</name>
        <group>EVENTS_GROUP</group>
        <description>Check new events in the db</description>
        <job-class>jobs.CheckNewEventsJob</job-class>
        <durability>true</durability>
        <recover>true</recover>
    </job>
    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>check-new-events-trigger</name>
            <group>EVENTSTRIGGER_GROUP</group>
            <job-name>check-new-events-job</job-name>
            <job-group>EVENTS_GROUP</job-group>
            <cron-expression>0 0/1 * * * ?</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
```

My job is configured to be

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class CheckNewEventsJob implements Job {
```

The goal of this job is to survive application restarts and keep track of all the last executions.

Any ideas where to look ?

Thanks a lot!